# How to get all the comments of the last telegram post on telethon?

Tags: python, telethon

I’m writing a function to get those who commented on a post in a telegram channel:

```
async def main():
if not await client.is_user_authorized():
    await client.start(bot_token=os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN'))

subscribed_channels = await get_my_channels(client=client)
for channel in subscribed_channels:
    print(f"Channel name: {channel.title}, ID: {channel.id}")
    message = await client.get_messages(channel.id, limit=1)
    if message[0].replies is not None:
        commenters = []

        try:
            comments = await client(functions.messages.GetDiscussionMessageRequest(
                peer=channel.id,
                msg_id=message[0].id
            ))

            for comment in comments.messages:
                if comment.from_id:
                    commenters.append(comment.from_id)
            for commenter in commenters:
                print(f"User ID: {commenter}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error getting commenters for the channel {channel.title}: {e}")
            continue

await client.disconnect()
```

But it returns responses like this:
Channel name: Name, ID: 1162560626
User ID: PeerChannel(channel_id=1162560626)

That is, it returns the id of the channel, although it should be commentators. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read all messages from specified channel, you can do this:

Firstly: Get real_id of channel you work with:

```
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

for dialog in client.get_dialogs()[:10]:
    print(dialog.title, dialog.id)
```

You `dialog.id` would contain something like `-1001557272771`. But you need real id, you would get it with

```
from telethon import utils

real_id, peer_type = utils.resolve_id(-1001557272771)
```

real_id is `1557272771`

To iterate over this channel messages do this:

```
for message in client.iter_messages(PeerChannel(channel_id=real_id)):
    message_id = message.id
    print(message.text)

    # iterate over comments of this message
    for reply in client.iter_messages(PeerChannel(channel_id=int(real_id)), reply_to=message.id):
        sender = reply.get_sender()  # this is User object
```

I'm not using async/await in this example, but I hope you will get the concept

Comment: The question is asking about comments to a post that exists as messages in the linked discussion group. Your answer unfortunately does not showcase how to get that linked discussion group.